# Stop media player in webview while another is playing

Tags: react-native

I have two tabs on React Native application. Both tabs are WebView and can play audio inside.

```
Step 1. At Tab 1. I play an audio

Step 2. I switch to Tab 2 and click on play audio button to play other audio

=> Result is both audio play at the same time.
```

Could you please show me how to pause audio of Tab 1 before play audio on Tab 2?